# Table Multicolumn - centering is off

Tags: header-footer, multicolumn, center

i am new to working with LaTeX and i am especially struggling with tables. Because i have really big tables in Excel and dont want to write all data (hundreds of entries) per hand i used the script "excel2latex" to convert the tables automatically. I already have added an new columntype (copied from internet) because centering did not work. The result is ok, but i still have problems with headers not centering in multicolumns. I colored the row grey and a block is still white as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccc|c}
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949}       & \multicolumn{3}{P{16.5em}|}{\textbf{not centered}} &  \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \textbf{Col0} & \multicolumn{1}{P{5.5em}}{\textbf{Col1}} & \multicolumn{1}{P{5.5em}}{\textbf{Col2}} & \multicolumn{1}{P{5.5em}|}{\textbf{Col3}} & \multicolumn{1}{P{5.5em}}{\textbf{Col4}} \\
        \midrule
        X     & -31.09\% & -22.84\% & -19.82\% & 0.09x \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} Y     & -32.31\% & -24.90\% & -22.98\% & 0.11x \\
        Z     & -37.67\% & -33.53\% & -31.79\% & 0.13x \\
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have any reason  to use a `p` column type  for a multicolumn of  plain `c` columns?

Comment: Should the header be centered over the first three data columns or across all four of them? If it's the former, just change `\multicolumn{3}{P{16.5em}|}{...}` to `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}`.

Comment: @Mico: The header should be centered over Col1, Col2 and Col3.

Comment: @Bernad: No, like i wrote - the table was auto generated by excel2latex script, i just copy & pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve centering of the header across the first three data columns (assuming all three columns have width 5.5em):

- `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}`

  This is fine if line breaking in the header cell isn't needed
- `\multicolumn{3}{P{\dimexpr16.5em+4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{...}`

  This is (obviously) more cumbersome, but it will permit automatic line breaking in the header cell.

Your calculation was off because it didn't take into account that the *usable* width of the header cell is not just 3 x 5.5em = 16.5em; you also have to take into account that the header cell spans two inter-column spaces, each of width `2\tabcolsep`. The total usable width of the header cell is therefore `16.5em+4\tabcolsep`. (By the way, a dead give-away that `16.5em` is *not* correct is the visual gap (of width `4\tabcolsep`!) in the background color of the first row in the screenshot you posted.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Caption}\label{tab:label}

    \begin{tabular}{ c | *{3}{P{5.5em}} | P{5.5em} }
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{P{16.5em}|}{\textbf{this is not centered}} &  \\
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{this is centered}} &  \\
    & \multicolumn{3}{P{\dimexpr16.5em+4\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\textbf{this is centered}} &  \\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} 
    \textbf{Col0} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col3} & \textbf{Col4} \\
    \hline
    X     & -31.09\% & -22.84\% & -19.82\% & 0.09x \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} 
    Y     & -32.31\% & -24.90\% & -22.98\% & 0.11x \\
    Z     & -37.67\% & -33.53\% & -31.79\% & 0.13x \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The line: "\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}" did it, now it looks like it should! All my appreciation & gratitude to you, thank you very much for the quick help!!!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Caption}\label{tab:label}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ c | *{3}{w{c}{5.5em}} | w{c}{5.5em} }[colortbl-like]
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{this is centered}} &  \\
   \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \RowStyle{\bfseries} Col0 & Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 \\
    \midrule
    X     & $-31.09$\% & $-22.84$\% & $-19.82$\% & $0.09$x \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} 
    Y     & $-32.31$\% & $-24.90$\% & $-22.98$\% & $0.11$x \\
    Z     & $-37.67$\% & $-33.53$\% & $-31.79$\% & $0.13$x \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]